# Serializer is displaying id instead of field names with Foreignkey

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm building a Django app which uses django rest framework and it shows the lists of buses in between two stops given by the user. For this purpose, I wanted to produce a json output as shown below.

```
   [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "start_time": "09:48:52",
        "end_time": "09:48:53",
        "start_stop": "A",
        "end_stop": "B",
        "bus_in_route": "Bus1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "start_time": "10:00:00",
        "end_time": "10:10:00",
        "start_stop": "B",
        "end_stop": "C",
        "bus_in_route": "Bus2"
    }
]
```

But I'm getting the output in the form of IDs. The field values in the child models (`Bus`, `BusStop`) are replaced with their IDs.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "start_time": "09:48:52",
        "end_time": "09:48:53",
        "start_stop": 1,
        "end_stop": 2,
        "bus_in_route": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "start_time": "10:00:00",
        "end_time": "10:10:00",
        "start_stop": 2,
        "end_stop": 3,
        "bus_in_route": 1
    }
]
```

**Code:**
**models.py**

```
class BusStop(models.Model): # model to store several bus stops
    stop_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.stop_name)


class Bus(models.Model):  # model to store names of several buses
    bus_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.bus_name
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Bus'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Buses'


class BusRoute(models.Model):  # lists out routes with start and end stops with the bus running between the stops
    start_stop = models.ForeignKey(BusStop,
                                related_name='start_stop',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    end_stop = models.ForeignKey(BusStop,
                                related_name='end_stop',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bus_in_route = models.ForeignKey(Bus,
                                related_name='bus_in_route',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.start_stop)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class BusRouteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BusRoute
        #fields=('firstname','lastname')
        fields='__all__'
        
class BusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bus_in_route = BusRouteSerializer(read_only=True,many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Bus
        fields='__all__'

class BusStopSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    start_stop = BusRouteSerializer(read_only=True,many=True)
    end_stop = BusRouteSerializer(read_only=True,many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = BusStop
        fields='__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class searchBusRoute(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = BusRouteSerializer
    filter_backends = [SearchFilter, OrderingFilter]

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = BusRoute.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

Is the usage of ForeignKey right?
In my `views.py`, I've tried printing the queryset using `start_stop__stop_name`. It correctly prints the stop names.
I'm facing the mentioned problem when I'm using serializers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add the view where the serialized is instantiated?

Comment: @KevinSmeeks I've added the views.py code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should note that `related_name` parameter given to `ForeignKey` field refers to its Model not its field.
For example in `start_stop` field, its `related_name` must be `"start_routes"` or something like this. It means that if you have an
`BusStop` object named `stop_obj`, you can access routes that starts from this stop by `stop_obj.start_routes.all()`.
Second for your problem, first you should remove `bus_in_route` from `BusSerializer` and also remove `start_stop` and `end_stop` from `BusStopSerializer`. If you want to show just name of models, also you can remove `BusSerializer` and `BusStopSerializer` entirely and then just convert `BusRouteSerializer` to this:

```
class BusRouteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    start_stop = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    end_stop = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    bus_in_route = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
            
    class Meta:
        model = BusRoute
        fields = '__all__'
                
    def get_start_stop(self, obj):
        return obj.start_stop.stop_name
            
    def get_end_stop(self, obj):
        return obj.end_stop.stop_name
            
    def get_bus_in_route(self, obj):
        return obj.bus_in_route.bus_name
```